# Add a ColSum to vector in r using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, column-sum

I am trying to add the sum (of all the counts in a specific vector) in my data frame in R. Specifically, I want to keep all the counts and then add a sum at the end. In excel, you would do =sum(A1:A5232). Additionally, I don't know the length of the specific vector. See below:

```
#sumarize by colname
  NewDepartment <- List %>%
  group_by(NewDepartment) %>%
  tally(sort=TRUE)
```

## The above code will give me the following:

```
                   NewDepartment     n
                       <chr> <int>
1                           <NA>   709
2                    Collections   454
3                      Telesales   281
4  Operations Control Management    93
5                   Underwriting    92
```

## I want a total count at the end like this:

```
                   NewDepartment     n
                       <chr> <int>
1                           <NA>   709
2                    Collections   454
3                      Telesales   281
4  Operations Control Management    93
5                   Underwriting    92
6                   Total Sum       1721
```

How do I get the row # 6 above??

Comment: @MikeH. It looks like `NewDepartment` is a column (as well as a data.frame), and the row names are integers, so I don't think your syntax will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NewDepartment = rbind(NewDepartment, 
    data.frame(NewDepartment = "Total Sum", n = sum(NewDepartment$n)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked. Is it possible to write that in one piece though? Meaning, if I changed the data.frame name to say "Final Department"?     
    ##sumarize by colname
    FinalDepartment <- List %>%
      group_by(NewDepartment) %>%
      tally(sort=TRUE) %>%                                                      
   FinalDepartment = rbind(FinalDepartment , 
    data.frame(NewDepartment = "Total Sum", n = sum(FinalDepartment $n)))